# Process each line of a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting

When I want to do something with each line in a file I usually write

```
cat my_file | while read a
do
gzip "$a"
done
```

The gzip is just an example it can be anything.

What I'm wondering is if there is another way to get the lines than `cat file | while read`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need to use `cat`:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < my_file
```

I don't think there's a simpler way though.

Comment: +1 In addition to avoiding a UUoC, doing it this way also prevents creating a subshell so the variables set during the loop will still be available after the loop (also you will still be in a directory that you `cd` to, if you do that).

Comment: I noticed I seem to need a blank newline at the end when I do this...

Answer (score 6):

The simplest, I think, would be to use `xargs`, e.g.,

```
xargs -L1 gzip < my_file
```

The `-L1` / `--max-lines=1` option tells `xargs` to process one input line at a time. You might take a look at [GNU parallel](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel), too, which is very similar to `xargs` but more powerful in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

```
IFS="\n\b"; for i in $MYROWOFCONTENT; do echo $i; done;
```